# How to Stop repeating my questions using array in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have added 5 question through array but every time my question repeats itself.
I think I have to use loop but I don't know how to use loop.
Can anyone please suggest me how to use loop and stop repeating my questions.

```
private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[]{
        new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
};
private int mCurrentIndex = 0;


private void updateQuestion() {
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
}

private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();

    if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {


            righttoast();
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();


    } else {

        wrongtoast();
        mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
        updateQuestion();

    }


}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
    {
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);

    }
    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            checkAnswer(true);

        }
    });
    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         checkAnswer(false);
        }
    });

    mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });
    mpreviousButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous_button);
    mpreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mCurrentIndex == 0) {
                return;
            }
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });

}

public void righttoast() {
    LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = li.inflate(R.layout.righttoast, (ViewGroup)       findViewById(R.id.right_toast_layout));
    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();


}

public void wrongtoast() {
    LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = li.inflate(R.layout.wrongtoast, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.wrong_toast_layout));
    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
}


}
```

Comment: Your code seems correct to me. what is your Question class ?

Comment: package com.example.puneet.geoquiz;

/**
 * Created by Puneet on 21-Nov-16.
 */

public class Question {
    private int mTextResId;
    private boolean mAnswerTrue;

    public Question(int textResId, boolean answerTrue) {
        mTextResId=textResId;
        mAnswerTrue=answerTrue;
    }


    public int getTextResId() {
        return mTextResId;
    }
    }
    public boolean isAnswerTrue() {

        return mAnswerTrue;
    }
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Change your `updateQuestion` method to this:

```
private void updateQuestion() {
    if(mCurrentIndex < mQuestionBank.length()){
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
        mCurrentIndex++;
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }
}
```

And then change the `checkAnswer` method to this:

```
private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();

    if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
        righttoast();
        updateQuestion();
    } else {
        wrongtoast();
        updateQuestion();
    }
}
```

Comment: my question repeats itself

Comment: can you post a github link to your project so i can take a look @PuneetKhattar